# Xcode import / use static libraray in framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-frameworks

I can't find anything to this topic.

My problem is:

I want to import a static Objective-C library into a framework. It seems no one wants to do it or has a problem with this, but Xcode can't help and even the apple developer forums have no post about this.

After this I want to use the framework to build an app for iOS and use the modules of the library. Is this even possible?

Comment: you want to create you own static library?

Comment: I have got an old static library. And know i want to import it to a ios-framwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static linked libraries can be linked and therefore "merged" into your framework binary directly. You just need to make sure that you have a compatible binary `*.a` for the architecture as well as the corresponding header files.

There are two possible scenarios:

**Best case scenario**

Your static linked library is a fat binary or you have two variants of your library that you can be merged via `lipo`. That means your binary includes all architectures for both simulator and devices and you can just link it against your framework.

**Worst case scenario**

You only have a static linked library for one type of architecture. That means you can only test your framework and app on that particular architecture, so either simulator or device.

Hope that helps!